# How to select the autoconf build directory?

Tags: c++, autoconf

Is there a way to set where autoconf generates the object files. I would like to have autoconf create all object files in a src/build/ instead of src/

I've tried setting VPATH but that doesn't seem to do anything.
VPATH = build

Comment: autoconf does not generate object files.  Your question is probably about automake, and autoconf is often used without automake.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do this by running `configure` from the directory where you want the object files.  For instance, if `configure` and all your code is in a directory named `src`, then starting from that directory, these commands should do what you want:

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ ../configure
$ make
```

If you're not using Automake, you have to write your Makefile.in to handle this case; there are [instructions for that](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/autoconf/Build-Directories.html#Build-Directories) in the [autoconf manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/autoconf/index.html).

Comment: I am using automake, but it fails on make. *** No rule to make target `IfxDatabase.lo', needed by `libifxapi.la'.  Stop. Any suggestions?

Comment: My bad, this does work just fine. I had  VPATH set in my Makefile.am in the src dir when I was messing around earlier to get it to work.

Comment: Keep in mind that you need to construct your Makefile.am correctly.  It is very easy to write a Makefile.am for which a vpath build (a build outside the source directory) does not work.  'make distcheck' will catch such errors.

Comment: What about placing the generated `configure` and other files in a separate directory, is that possible?

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 The generated `configure` needs to be at the top level of the source tree or it won't work correctly and also people won't be able to find it. [`AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Input.html) can be used to move most of the other files.  But you should really ask a new question and explain in more detail what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Just want a full out of tree build, nothing generated in-tree. Lazy for new question now, will ping you if I do :-)